Designing scalable tooltips & toggletips
I am working on creating a design system for our product and completed with an audit. While working on the tooltip component, I came across some patterns which I am unfamiliar with, can someone have a look and help me understand what these are exactly and if it is the right way to use them?
Here's what I am referring to:



I also have a need for toggletips in the design library but I am not sure if they should look exactly the same as tooltips or should they be highlighted separately. These are shown on click and stay opened when the cursor moves away from the icon.
Here's an example:


What I'm looking for is how I can make the interactions and experience better and more intuitive, also looking for feedback where the design patterns/component usage is wrong and how I can I can fix this and create a fresh component for the design system which covers multiple components.
Here's what our current normal tooltip looks like:


This is extremely broad and you're mixing tooltips with popups (and some pretty good examples of what NOT to do). If your use case is just the last one, that is enough, you don't need anything else (well, you can add  arrow position depending on element position so tooltip is always visible)

Carbon Design System includes both tooltip and toggletip components.
The overlays can look exactly the same.
So the difference is made by trigger elements.

Toggletips vs Tooltips
In case of tooltips, the trigger can be anything. But toggletips require a visually distinct element.
Carbon gives as example the same info icon for both components, but I find that to be confusing. Ideally, you would have 2 different icons, so that your users know exactly what behavior to expect from each of them.
A simple solution: choose a set of icons as being reserved only for toggletips and never use them for tooltips. Tooltips can use anything else as trigger.

Toggletips vs Popups vs Tooltips
When comparing toggletips to standard popups, the difference also lies in the UI trigger.
In your design library, you need to clearly define what trigger elements are available for toggletips vs tooltips vs popups, and never mix them, otherwise you risk confusing your users.
A simple solution: choose a set of icons for toggletips and another set for popups, and use tooltips for anything else.
